# WPF IChangeTracking with tabs

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, observablecollection

I am working on the settings interface for a WPF program. I would like to have a window for editing user settings with multiple tabs for the different categories of settings. I have got most of it working but am struggling with binding the save button's enabled property.

Here is the XAML for the main window.

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource WindowsSettings}">
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding TabHeader}" />
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding TabContent}" />
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TabControl>
    <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Save" Margin="0,0,10,10" Padding="5,3"></Button>
    <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Cancel" Margin="0,0,59,10" Padding="5,3"></Button>
</Grid>
```

The tabModel class

```
public class TabModel
{
    public string TabHeader { get; set; }
    public FrameworkElement TabContent { get; set; }
}
```

Tabs Collection with initialization

```
private ObservableCollection<TabModel> _tabs;
public ObservableCollection<TabModel> Tabs
{
    get { return _tabs; }
    set
    {
        if (_tabs == value) return;
        _tabs = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Tabs);
    }
}
private void InitSettingsTabs()
{
    Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabModel>();

   //add main tab control
    var tab = new TabModel()
        {
            TabContent = new GeneralSettings(),
            TabHeader = "General"
        };
    Tabs.Add(tab);
}
```

GeneralSettings is a UserControl that implements IChangeTracking. I would like to bind the save buttons enabled property to check each TabContent.IsChanged property and if any are true then enable the save button.

**EDIT**
GeneralSettings is a UserControl whose datacontext implements IChangeTracking.

Comment: `GeneralSettings is a UserControl that implements IChangeTracking` - Wrong. Change tracking is a DATA related concept, and is not a View concern. It is a Model concern or at the very least a ViewModel concern. Remove your business logic from the UI and learn WPF and MVVM properly.

Comment: @HighCore see my edit, I incorrectly stated that my user control implements IChangeTracking when in fact it is my view model that does so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to create a property at the same level as the `ObservableCollection<TabModel>` which performs the logic of "aggregate all TabContent.IsChanged values", and then bind to that property.

Something like:

```
public bool IsSaveEnabled
{
    get
    {
        return Tabs.Any(a => a.IsChanged);
    }
}
```

With XAML of:

```
<Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Save" Enabled={Binding IsSaveEnabled} Margin="0,0,10,10" Padding="5,3"></Button>
```

You'll also need a way to notifying the View when the IsSaveEnabled aggregate property changes. You can do this by listening to the PropertyChanged notifications coming from your TabModel classes, which in turn will have to propagate the PropertyChanged notifications from the FrameworkElement inside (so it knows when IsChanged changes).

Its a little strange to be storing FrameworkElements directly inside a View Model though. I would recommend against that, you're muddying the waters between the View Model and the View.

Comment: Great answer, this is exactly what I was looking for. Using the FrameworkElement was code left over from some initial testing. Ill be switching that out for the appropriate base view model class.

Comment: Good to hear (both this being the answer you were looking for and that FrameworkElements living in your view model was a temporary thing).